# Bluetooth manager window won't open

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using a USB Bluetooth dongle on my Raspberry Pi. So far I managed to connect the device and pair it using the terminal. Yet the desktop/GUI Bluetooth manager won't open. I can see the icon on the desktop and as you can see it I can even right-click it for options but none of them open. I've tried everything described [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23996&p=237557) with no success. Any ideas why does this happen and how could I fix it?

UPDATE: following @Patrick's suggestion I did a `pkill blueman-applet` and `blueman-applet` and got the following output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pkill blueman-applet
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ blueman-applet
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Loading configuration plugins
blueman-applet version 1.22 starting
Using gconf config backend
_________
Load (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:68)
['DhcpClient', 'Indicator', 'TransferService', 'StatusIcon', 'DiscvManager', 'NetUsage', 'PPPSupport', 'AuthAgent', 'KillSwitch', 'NMDUNSupport', 'PulseAudio', 'StandardItems', 'Menu', 'SerialManager', 'Headset', 'NMPANSupport', 'ExitItem', 'RecentConns', 'DBusService', 'Networking', 'PowerManager'] 
Using gconf config backend
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Headset.Headset'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StatusIcon.StatusIcon'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Indicator.Indicator'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Networking.Networking'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
load_nap_settings (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:47)
Loading NAP settings 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DBusService.DBusService'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.NMDUNSupport.NMDUNSupport'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Menu.Menu'> 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Menu.py:40: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised
  self.__menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Menu.py:40: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised
  self.__menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Menu.py:40: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised
  self.__menu = gtk.Menu()
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.NMPANSupport.NMPANSupport'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.PowerManager.PowerManager'> 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/Functions.py:255: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-images after class was initialised
  item = gtk.ImageMenuItem(text)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/Functions.py:255: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
  item = gtk.ImageMenuItem(text)
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.TransferService.TransferService'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.KillSwitch.KillSwitch'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
on_load (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:40)
Using the new killswitch system 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.AuthAgent.AuthAgent'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
Not loading DhcpClient because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DiscvManager.DiscvManager'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
update_menuitems (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py:132)
warning: Adapter is None 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.RecentConns.RecentConns'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
Not loading PPPSupport because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StandardItems.StandardItems'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:142)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.SerialManager.SerialManager'> 
Using gconf config backend
_________
update_state (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/KillSwitchNG.py:162)
State: True 
_________
on_switch_added (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:61)
killswitch registered 0 
_________
on_dbus_name_owner_change (/usr/bin/blueman-applet:102)
org.bluez owner changed to :1.1 
_________
set_nap (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:80)
set nap False 
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.bluez:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
_________
Run (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:216)
Function on_manager_state_changed on Networking Failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 220, in Run
    ret = getattr(inst, function)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py", line 45, in on_manager_state_changed
    self.update_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py", line 69, in update_status
    self.set_nap(self.Config.props.nap_enable or False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py", line 83, in set_nap
    adapters = self.Applet.Manager.ListAdapters()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/utils.py", line 28, in warp
    raise errors.parse_dbus_error(exception)
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="ListAdapters" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
_________
Run (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:216)
Function on_manager_state_changed on AuthAgent Failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 220, in Run
    ret = getattr(inst, function)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AuthAgent.py", line 49, in on_manager_state_changed
    adapters = self.Applet.Manager.ListAdapters()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/utils.py", line 28, in warp
    raise errors.parse_dbus_error(exception)
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="ListAdapters" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
_________
update_menuitems (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py:132)
warning: Adapter is None 
_________
Run (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:216)
Function on_manager_state_changed on RecentConns Failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 220, in Run
    ret = getattr(inst, function)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/RecentConns.py", line 192, in on_manager_state_changed
    adapters = self.Applet.Manager.ListAdapters()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/utils.py", line 28, in warp
    raise errors.parse_dbus_error(exception)
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="ListAdapters" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Indicator.py", line 76, in enumerate_connections
    adapters = self.Applet.Manager.ListAdapters()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/utils.py", line 28, in warp
    raise errors.parse_dbus_error(exception)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="ListAdapters" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
_________
on_obex_owner_changed (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/TransferService.py:81)
obex owner changed: :1.15 
Using gconf config backend
_________
on_started (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/applet/Transfer.py:91)
opp Started 
_________
on_started (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/applet/Transfer.py:91)
ftp Started 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py", line 95, in timeout
    self.adapter_state = self.get_adapter_state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py", line 100, in get_adapter_state
    adapters = self.Applet.Manager.ListAdapters()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/utils.py", line 28, in warp
    raise errors.parse_dbus_error(exception)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.17" (uid=1000 pid=2753 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/blueman-applet ") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="ListAdapters" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=2222 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
_________
on_power_state_query (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:88)
True 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:176)
off False 
foff False 
on True 
current state True 
new state True
```

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal, do `pkill blueman-applet` to kill the applet process, and then `blueman-applet` to start it up in the terminal. Try to click one of the options, and then provide us whatever output is shown in the terminal when doing so.

Comment: Just updated my original post, thanks for the help!

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Same problem!  I tried the suggestion from @javaj0hn, and the window opened but it doesn't show any devices for pairing, and all the buttons are grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a fix but try to click "Turn Bluetooth Off" Then try to open the bluetooth manager. It should prompt you to turn bluetooth back on and then the manager will open. This worked for me.

Comment: I owe you a couple of beers or their equivalent.

Comment: Doesn't always work. Using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (as noted in the comment above).  I am using the Plugable USB-BT4LE bluetooth adapter on a Pi 2.  This page (http://plugable.com/2013/12/10/using-the-plugable-usb-bt4le-bluetooth-adapter-with-the-raspberry-pi) provided the answer:

> If the Bluetooth utility does not see the Bluetooth adapter try the
>   following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/group
> ```
>
> {change line 8 from “lp:x:7:” to “lp:x:7:pi” save and exit}
>
> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```

That did the trick for me!